# Identify when I return to ViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have two views with their controllers. 
The application start with the `FirstViewController`. 
Then with a button I open the `SecondViewController`.

With other button I dismiss the `SecondViewController` to return to `FirstViewController`.

Is there any way to detect that in `FirstViewController` that it has recovered focus?

EDIT: Ok I look the answers and I use `viewWillAppear` but don't work if I use a `UIModalPresentationFormSheet`.

```
-(IBAction)openSecondView{
    SecondViewController *screen = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    screen.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    screen.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
    [self presentModalViewController:screen animated:YES];
    [screen release];
}
```

And close this view with close button.

`viewWillAppear` never called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a delegate (Protocol) method. Call the delegate method just before dismissing the SecondViewController.

For more info on delegate, see [delegate](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/objective-c/the-basics-of-protocols-and-delegates.html)

Answer (score 2):

implement UIViewController's viewWillAppear method

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

}
```

Comment: I used it but didn't work. I edited the question with more information. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

inside the `viewWillAppear` of the `FirstViewController`

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    NSLog(@"view 1 focused");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

implementation of the viewWillAppear: callback will work only if you use navigation controller or tabbarcontroller for displaying another controller + with such approach you will need to check somehow if this is only the first appearance of the view, or was called by any other reason;

using a delegate, as described by Gomathi above is a much better option!

Answer (score 0):

Depends how you are setting up the first view controller. Encapsulate it within UINavigationViewController (and if you do not want the navigation bar, you can always set it to hidden ( `[self.navigationController.navigationBar setHidden:YES]` ). `ViewWillAppear` will work then.